# Where to put "professionally"?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct:

- This call is being professionally answered by Company A.
- This call is professionally being answered by Company A.
- This call is being answered professionally by Company A.

Both seem a bit awkward. Is there a better phrasing?

Comment: The adverb, "professionally" can move about in this sentence, and to my ear doesn't sound fixed in place....so it could even be placed at the end of the sentence.  Others will argue that it changes the meaning.  I think it does slightly but not significantly.  I don't have "proof" that "professionally" must be placed in a certain slot in the sentence, so I cannot post an answer, merely a comment.

Comment: The safest place for a movable adverb modifying the verb phrase is after the first auxiliary verb (i.e, the first one).

Comment: @JohnLawler Isn't the first verb "is" an auxiliary verb? or You consider "is being" as one auxiliary verb?

Comment: You're right. Actually, none of them sound good, because _professionally_ is not a manner adverb that can apply to an automated device, nor to answering a telephone call. So it doesn't really belong in the sentence. People or companies who talk about professionalism (let alone mentioning it to everyone who calls) are usually too busy to demonstrate much.

Answer (score 1):

All of them are correct, but I'd opt for either the first or the last. I'd say the last would be the most common construction.